# Dropping all records in entity during data migration

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, core-data-migration

I was wondering if someone has experimented dropping data records during core data custom migration. Is it a rather nonsensical question to ask to do due to the original intent of data migration functionality? How would one go about doing that?

Comment: I think creating a mapping model and deleting the entity mapping will do the trick.

Comment: What do you mean by deleting the entity mapping? As in, for the source to give it nil? I was thinking about doing that today but I haven't gotten around to trying it out yet.

Comment: In Xcode, select the mapping model, select the entity mapping and type a backspace. I don't know if it will work, I didn't try it.

Answer (score 0):

What about deleting the persistent store! If u want to delete all data in migration. You don't even need to migrate.

Delete persistent store.

Delete ManageObjectContext.

Create context with your new model.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to delete only certain data. Thanks for your input though!